# Should indexers always refer to a discrete sequence?

Tags: c#, indexer

Should indexers always refer to a discrete sequence?
I am tempted to think no, but I would like to ask what others think.

The question started after a 'shortcut' was made on a polynomial class.

```
Polynomial p = new Polynomial(coefficients);
```

The normal way to calculate y = p(5.2) was to use the following method call:

```
double y = p.Evaluate(5.2);
```

The shortcut that was made (using an indexer of type double) was:

```
double y = p[5.2];
```

I think the idea was that the polynomial (a continuous function) is being viewed as a sort of analog array or continuous array, if that makes sense.  However, the Evaluate function comes from the interface IMathFunction.  This interface is also used on an interpolation class:

```
CubicSplineInterpolator f = new CubicSplineInterpolator(arrayOfPoints)
```

There is an issue here because the interpolator classes already have a public indexer of type int to access their array of points used for interpolation.  The interpolator can act like a continuous function (within its limits) but if the shortcut gets rolled out to all IMathFunction classes then f[5.0] and f[5] would return different objects and may be confusing when reading the code.

```
double y;
Point<double> p;

// ... some other code

CubicSplineInterpolator f = new CubicSplineInterpolator(arrayOfPoints)
y = f[5.0];
p = f[5];
```

Should I be worried about this use of an indexer of type double or is this what they should be used for?

Comment: Well, it was a bad idea and you found out why.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the interpolator can not be viewed as a discrete array of points and a continuous analog array at the same time.  This is the confusion right?

Comment: @Hans Passant Although how does this differ from `f.Evaluate(5.0)` and `f.Evaluate(5)`? I don't disagree with the conclusion, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [indexed property design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229061.aspx) guidelines, "indexed properties allow array-like access to groups of items." So the intent is clearly to have the indexers come from a discrete set. Furthermore:

> **Avoid indexers with parameter types other than System.Int32, System.Int64, System.String, System.Object, enumerations, or generic
>   type parameters.**
>
> If the design requires other types of parameters, you should strongly
>   reevaluate whether the member really represents access to a logical
>   collection. If not, use methods instead and consider choosing a method
>   name that begins with Get or Set.

In purely mathematical terms, functions are defined as mappings, possibly over infinite sets like the real numbers, .NET languages use methods to represent such mappings. That is the pattern you should follow.

Note that delegates are a special case of this, where the `Invoke` method is treated as a default method. This lets you write `myDelegate(arg1)` instead of `myDelegate.Invoke(arg1)`. This is a special case, though. Default methods are not available in C# or VB.

Maybe it is better to think of indexers as subscripts. After all, in mathematics, elements of a collection like a vector or sequence are usually represented by the name of the collection with a subscript. Only very rarely do you see f<sub>x</sub> represent the value of a function f at a value x.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, I like you suggestion of thinking of indexers as subscripts.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing with an indexer is usually done with a method... Although you *can* use an indexer as if it were a method, it's not its intended semantics, so it will probably confuse most people who read your code. So I would advice against it: reserve indexers for direct access to a specific item in a collection, or for operations with a similar purpose.

Comment: So I guess this kind of rules out the use of indexers of type double then? and the idea of a continuous or analog array is a non-starter? - Thanks for your help Thomas.

Comment: @Ben, this is only my opinion, it doesn't mean it's a "non-starter"; others probably have different opinions on this question. It doesn't feel right to me, but if you have a good reason to do it, you're free to ignore my advice... after all, the language allows it ;)